# Copy relevant lines of text file containing string to another file

Tags: text-processing

I have a constantly updated text file with lines like:

```
On 29-08-2018 18:30:29:05 bacteria detected 20 Machine learning error 10
```

and so on (I get a new line every second).

I will get the start and stop times (in the format of `18:30:29`) from my C++ program. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
string er = "system ./RUN.sh ";
er = er + start + stop;
system(er.c_str());
```

and then in the .sh file you do

```
read start
read stop
```

in order for the inputs to be read

My next question is how will I read the line from the file to search for my relevant time and copy the whole line until the stop time will come to a new file?

The file that I am searching for the relevant times is already copied into a new location and will not be updated only replaced on the next .sh run

The algorithm will be something like:

```
if (Log_29-08-2018.txt->readline() contain "18:30:29")
while (RESULT.txt->readline() not contain "20:30:29")
/MINI_LOG/Log_29-08-2018.txt->writeline()
Log_29-08-2018.txt->readline()
done
fi
```

And also I need the file `/MINI_LOG/Log_29-08-2018.txt` to be updated on the next run unless it will be another day.

Every new day I am getting a new source file so there won't be any time repetitions

I already looked at your examples but they were not exactly what I need and it gave me a lot of errors.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make it ask only one question; you can post the other one separately. Also, please clarify what this C program is and what this sh program is. At the moment, it is very hard to understand what you already have and what you need.

Comment: I tried to make it more understandable I hope. It is a little bit of complex question that I am sitting on it for the entire week.

Comment: Are you certain you get a new record *every* second? Is it possible that the start and/or end timestamps will not exist in the file?

Comment: No it is impossible our system is real time we even getting repetitions in terms of millisecounds

Comment: Have a look at this line: `er = er + start + stop;` -- you don't appear to be putting a space between the start and stop arguments.

Answer (score 2):

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is a good tool for this: compact code, good performance. RUN.sh would look like

```sh
#!/bin/sh
awk -v start="$1" -v stop="$2" '
    $3 ~ "^"start {p = 1}
    $3 ~ "^"stop  {p = 0}
    p
' logfile > resultfile
```

Comment: Getting empty file in resultfile :(

Comment: Or maybe it is because I used start='14:07:14' -v stop='15:32:20' or it should work regardless?

Comment: Is the timestamp always in the 3rd field of the log's records?

Comment: No it was the second one and it works now thanks alot

Comment: There is only one problem remaining on the second write it overwrites the previous data? (if there is no solution not a big problem will just make array of files)

Comment: you can use `>>` to append to the result file instead of `>` which truncates.